# ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I get this error message when I am building the model:

```
When using the attribute ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE you cannot use the field name "attribute" ...
```

The problem is, that I have to use this field name, because it is in a table which is created and used by virtuemart. Alias does not work either.

```
product_attribute: { name: product_attribute as attribute,  type: clob(16777777) }
```

So, what can I do? Can I turn `ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE` off or do I get problems with that. In case I can, how can I do that?

Could there be a problem with turning `ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE` off? And if there is one (or more), what will it be?

I am thankful for any advice!

---

Additional Information:

Definition in BaseJosVmProduct: `@property clob $product_attribute`

schema.yml:

```
JosVmProduct:
  columns:
    product_id:                     { type: int, notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    vendor_id:                      { type: int, notnull: true, default: 0 }
    product_parent_id:              { type: int, notnull: true, default: 0 }
    product_sku:                    { type: string(64), , notnull: true, default: '' }
    product_s_desc:                 { type: string(255), default: null }
    product_desc:                   { type: clob(16777777) }
    product_thumb_image:            { type: string(255), default: null }
    product_full_image:             { type: string(255), default: null }
    product_publish:                { type: string(1), default: null }
    product_weight:                 { type: decimal(10), scale: 4, default: null }
    product_weight_uom:             { type: string(32), default: 'pounds.' }
    product_length:                 { type: decimal(10), scale: 4, default: null }
    product_width:                  { type: decimal(10), scale: 4, default: null }
    product_height:                 { type: decimal(10), scale: 4, default: null }
    product_lwh_uom:                { type: string(32), default: 'inches' }
    product_url:                    { type: string(255), default: null }
    product_in_stock:               { type: int, default: null }
    product_available_date:         { type: int, default: null }
    product_availability:           { type: string(56), notnull: true, default: '' }
    product_special:                { type: string(1), default: null }
    product_discount_id:            { type: int, default: null }
    ship_code_id:                   { type: int, default: null }
    cdate:                          { type: int, default: null }
    mdate:                          { type: int, default: null }
    product_name:                   { type: string(64), default: null }
    product_sales:                  { type: int, notnull: true, default 0 }
    product_attribute:              { name: product_attribute as attribute, type: clob(16777777) }
    custom_attribute:               { type: clob(16777777), notnull: true }
    product_tax_id:                 { type: int(2), notnull: true, default: '0' }
    product_unit:                   { type: string(32), default: null }
    product_packaging:              { type: int, default: null }
    webinar_duration:               { type: string(50), default: null }
```

Comment: What doctrine version you are using, 1.2 or 2.0? Also, entity definition could help.

Comment: I am using doctrine 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found better solution, put this in ProjectConfiguration class:

```
public function configureDoctrine()
        {
        $isCli = (php_sapi_name() == "cli");
        if(true == $isCli)
            {
            Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, false);
            }
        }
```

Works automatically detecting CLI context and switching proper ATTR off.

Comment: I wrote about this on my blog: http://blog.kowalczyk.cc/2011/09/16/symfony-blad-when-using-the-attribute-attr_auto_accessor_override-you-cannot-use-the-field-name/ . It's in Polish, but I hope that you'll manage to read it with Google Translate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for this:

- switch `ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE` temporarily off in 'mySymfonyFolder/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins//sfDoctrinePlugin/config/sfDoctrineConfiguration.class.php'
- create the classes
- switch it on again

If you want set the field in the code, you have to do:

- switch `ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE` off with ->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, false);
- do the setting
- switch it on again with ->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);